# Flutter what is the correct return method type?

Tags: flutter

From this API

```
List customerItems = await _helper.get('/Customers/v1/GetItems/$cid/$pfType/$targetId');

var groupByCustomerItems = groupBy(customerItems, (obj) => obj['itemtype']).map((key, value) => MapEntry(
    key,
    value.map((item) {
      return new CustomerItem.fromJson(item);
    }).toList()));
```

I get following result:

```
{Device: [Instance of 'CustomerItem', Instance of 'CustomerItem'], Dial-Up: [Instance of 
'CustomerItem', Instance of 'CustomerItem'], Domain: [Instance of 'CustomerItem'], EMAIL:             
[Instance of 'CustomerItem', Instance of 'CustomerItem', Instance of 'CustomerItem', 
Instance of 'CustomerItem', Instance of 'CustomerItem', Instance of 'CustomerItem', Instance 
of 'CustomerItem', Instance of 'CustomerItem', Instance of 'CustomerItem', Instance of 
'CustomerItem', Instance of 'CustomerItem', Instance of 'CustomerItem', Instance of 
'CustomerItem', Instance of 'CustomerItem', Instance of 'CustomerItem'], HSI: [Instance of 
'CustomerItem'], vo.phone: [Instance of 'CustomerItem', Instance of 'CustomerItem', Instance 
of 'CustomerItem', Instance of 'CustomerItem', Instance of 'CustomerItem', Instance of 
'CustomerItem', Instance of 'CustomerItem', Instance of 'CustomerItem', Instance of 
'CustomerItem']}
```

It is a list of CustomerItems group by type. What will be the return type of the method?

```
Future<List<CustomerItem>>
```

seems not to be correct... Thanks for any help and tips.

Answer (score 1):

It's a map `Map<String, List<CustomerItem>>`

Answer (score 1):

Should be a `Map<String, List<CustomerItem>>`

Comment: This is correct, thx. But passing this response to a widget I cannot loop over it... hmmm

Comment: You can loop over it with the `.map` method again. But this sounds like a different problem so consider opening a new question.